# Mocking static fields with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have something like this (it is a third party library so I have to work with this design):

```
ClassA.conn1.getObjectA().getIntValue()
```

ClassA is a normal class, and inside it there is a public static field (conn1). This conn1 is a class which have a connection and some other values which are used in the application (in my case that ObjectA).

This value is passed as parameter in the dao I am mocking. That value is mocked as  Matchers.anyInt() but I get a NullPointerException because conn1 is null (not the expected int)

I tried some things PowerMockito, the WhiteBox, but without success. Now I have done this, but I get the same NullPointerException

```
Mockito.when(ClassA.conn1.getObjectA()).thenReturn(new ObjectA(2));
```

The question is, how can I mock it to get the ObjectA or the int value of the ObjectA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import static x.y.z.Mockito.*;

ObjectA objectA = mock(ObjectA.class);
when(objectA.getIntValue()).thenReturn(1));

Conn conn1 = mock(Conn.class);
when(conn1.getObjectA()).thenReturn(objectA);

ClassA.conn1 = conn1;
```

Comment: About the last line, conn1 and objectA are different objects (in fact objectA is a field of conn1), so that does not work